# String to time format, then Time span decreasing each second

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Code is not working as i planned: each timer interval this cell value decreases by one second and then the cell value will change, but with this code the value is the same "00:30:00"  and no exceptions.

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    timer2.Interval = 1000;

    string ti = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString(); //The cell Value at this command line instance equals "00:30:00"

    DateTime tint = DateTime.Parse(ti); //I Want to convert cell value "00:30:00" from string to datetime

    DateTime updated = tint.Add(new TimeSpan(0,0,-1)); //Subtract one second from "00:30:00"

    row.Cells[4].Value = updated.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss").ToString();//Change cell value after subtracting
}
```

Comment: use `TimeSpan` instead of `DateTime`

Comment: In which line should i replace 'TimeSpan' by 'DateTime' @EhsanSajjad

Comment: `DateTime tint = DateTime.Parse(ti);` to `TimeSpan tint = TimeSpan.Parse(ti);`

Comment: 'DateTime updated = tint.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, -1));' the R.H.S of the equal sign is giving error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.TimeSpan' to 'System.DateTime'

Comment: So I assume you've tried to debug. What did that tell you? Did it go into your event handler? What is the value of `updated`? Does it look correct before you turn it into a string? Does it look correct after you've turned it into a string? Basically what is your actual problem and what have you tried to do to fix it?

Comment: It almost certainly won't fix your problem but a clearer way of removing a second is to use `tint.AddSeconds(-1)` Saves you needing to create a timespan object each time round just for one second and I personally think it is much more readable.

Comment: after i found another logic error its shows me 00:30:00 to 12:30:00 since it uses 12-hour Format and this is unwanted behavior, the last answer worked with me cause "00:30:00" is a TimeSpan not DateTime Thanks for help @Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the real issue is that you're using a `DateTime` instead of a `TimeSpan`. Your string "00:30:00" is a `TimeSpan`, not a `DateTime`. Something like this should work:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer2.Interval = 1000;

    //The cell Value at this command line instance equals "00:30:00"
    ti = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();

    TimeSpan tint = TimeSpan.Parse(ti);

    // Subtract one second
    TimeSpan updated = tint.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    //Change cell value after subtracting
    row.Cells[4].Value = updated.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
}
```

Or if you want to be really tricky, you can do it in one long statement:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer2.Interval = 1000;

    row.Cells[4].Value = TimeSpan
        .Parse(row.Cells[4].Value.ToString())
        .Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot  Rufus

Comment: This one long statement better than before Thanks Rufus

Comment: Glad it helped. By the way, setting the timer `Interval` inside the `Tick` event is probably not the best place unless you're trying to prevent any other methods from ever changing the `Interval`.

Comment: I wrote it in the question only not in my code,so useful tip

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is on this line:

```
DateTime updated = tint.Add(new TimeSpan(-0,0,1));
```

To decrease  TimeSpan by one second you need the following:

```
DateTime updated = tint.Add(new TimeSpan(0,0,-1));
//Syntax is TimeSpan(hours,minutes,seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `updated.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss").ToString();` you should use `updated.ToString(@"HH\:mm\:ss").ToString();` because your solution turns 00:30:00 to 12:30:00 since it uses 12-hour Format. I dont know if this is wanted behaviour.

Also you Need to use `tint.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, -1))` to subtract a second instead of subtracting 0 days and adding 1 second (which is what you currently do).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the cell value is not updated

Comment: @MohamedWagih is it not updated on the UI or did you see it while Debugging? If its not updated on the UI, did you use a `INotifyPropertyChanged` if youre working with WPF?

Comment: after i found another logic error its shows me 00:30:00 to 12:30:00 since it uses 12-hour Format and this is unwanted behavior, the last answer worked with me cause "00:30:00" is a `TimeSpan` not `DateTime` Thanks alot @ThFi